# Mnemonic seed from signing and verification key?

Tags: wallet, transaction, eutxo

I followed an iohk tutorial for minting native assets. The result is that I have a eutxo with the assets, but not enough ada in the eutxo to send them out. I added more ada to the wallet, but the process they describe limits your interaction to the eutxo.

I'd like to restore this wallet in daedalus to abstract away this work. I have the payment signing key and payment verification key that the tutorial creates, but it never creates a mnemonic seed. Is there a way to restore a wallet in daedalus using these payment signing and verification keys, or to generate a seed from them?

Here is the guide I followed, for reference:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brief HD infographic describing wallet key generation in Cardano (and other blockchains like Bitcoin).

[image]

The Master Seed is derived from a mnemonic phrase pulled from the [BIP-39 wordlist](https://www.blockplate.com/pages/bip-39-wordlist).

As such, all possible mnemonic combinations are actually a subset of all possible master seeds. If a master seed is generated raw without the use of mnemonics, it will likely be outside this subset and will not be convertible to a 24 word phrase.

Your best bet would likely be to generate a new set of wallets derived from mnemonic instead of a raw master seed (used in cardano-cli).

Answer (score 0):

There is no other officially supported way for importing into Daedalus other than the one from mnemonic phrase.
There's also no way to generate mnemonic from the preexisting signature keys.

You should top up the address with ada, so that there is enough ada to be included in your outgoing transactions.
There should be at least `minUTxOValue` (currently 1Ada) included in each transaction.