# Can you open a cardano-cli wallet on nami or daedalus?

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, daedalus, nami-wallet

I'm extremely worried a wallet through cli can be corrupted as i'm using a virtual machine which often crashes and deletes to itself. In other crypto wallets you can insert a secret phrase or a key to open the address in other extension wallets. Is this possibly in cardano?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seed phrases following the [bip-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) standard do exist for Cardano. However, there is no way to generate a seed phrase from a signing key. Therefore, the private key generated with the cardano-cli cannot be imported into a wallet that uses the seed phase recovery method.

To quote the answer given [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4759/1071)

> Your best bet would likely be to generate a new set of wallets derived from mnemonic instead of a raw master seed (used in cardano-cli).

Answer (score 0):

> In other crypto wallets you can insert a secret phrase or a key to open the address in other extension wallets. Is this possibly in cardano?

Yes. It is possible.

As an aside: creating wallets from cardano-cli, you get `paymeny.vkey` and `payment.skey` . If you keep the keys safe from the malfunctioning VM, you can use them to recover the wallet from other machines.